# Can Trac connect into SVN repos from other server?

Tags: svn, trac, svn-repository

Can Trac connect to an SVN repository from a different server than the one in the SVN repository?

Currently I have Trac and SVN on the same server and they work correctly, but I want to have Trac on one server and SVN on another. I have searched for information about the topic, but I have not found much information.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Trac cannot directly connect to a Subversion server on a remote server. The effective workaround I have seen is to use `svnsync` create a read-only mirror of the remote repository.

Comment: Thanks for reply.

I followed the steps in the trac documentation about subversion replication but I am getting an error message saying : 

svnsync: E165001: Change of revision property locked by hook pre-revprop-change (exit code 1) with exit:
Changing revision properties other than svn: log is prohibited.

Steps I did:

$ svnadmin create /backup/svn/repos/Tprueba.Harold
$ chmod +x /backup/svn/repos/Tprueba.Harold/hooks/pre-revprop-change
$ svnsync init file:///backup/svn/repos/Tprueba.Harold/ http://172.21.10.98/repos/Tprueba.Harold/ 

Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: See [svnsync.txt](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/svnsync.txt) for setup instructions.

Comment: I change the hook pre-revprop-change and now it works.                                                       Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions in  https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/svnsync.txt to change the hook pre-revprop-change and with this https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracMigrate#SubversionReplication I could do the replication.